# QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on ProgramWindow "", which already has a layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, layout, pyqt, pyqt5

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    programWindow = ProgramWindow()

    programWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


class ProgramWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setup_main_window()
        self.set_window_layout()

    def setup_main_window(self):
        self.resize( 800, 600  )
        self.setWindowTitle( "Test" )

    def set_window_layout(self):
        self.startSimulationButton = QPushButton( 'Start Simulation' )

        horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        horizontalLayout.addWidget( self.startSimulationButton )

        horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox( "My Group" )
        horizontalGroupBox.setLayout( horizontalLayout )

        main_vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_vertical_layout.addWidget( horizontalGroupBox )
        self.setLayout( main_vertical_layout )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run it, it shows a empty window and throws this error on the console:

`QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on ProgramWindow "", which already has a layout`

I already looked on [QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QWidget "", which already has a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450598/qlayout-attempting-to-add-qlayout-to-qwidget-which-already-has-a-layout) but I do not think I am doing any of that, what wrong with this code?

Commenting out the last line `self.setLayout( main_vertical_layout )` fixes it, but of course, does not show anything on the screen.

This code should Create a `QGroupBox` with the layout `QHBoxLayout` and put the `QGroupBox` inside the layout `QVBoxLayout`. And the `QVBoxLayout` should be attached on my main window:

1. QHBoxLayout
2. QGroupBox
3. QVBoxLayout
4. ProgramWindow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that said @Aviad your code might look like this:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton,
                             QHBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QVBoxLayout)

class ProgramWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setup_main_window()
        self.set_window_layout()

    def setup_main_window(self):
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.resize( 800, 600  )
        self.setWindowTitle( "Test" )

    def set_window_layout(self):
        self.startSimulationButton = QPushButton( 'Start Simulation' )

        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget) 
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget( self.startSimulationButton )

        self.horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox( "My Group" )
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget( self.horizontalGroupBox )

        self.main_vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout( self.main_vertical_layout )
        button1 = QPushButton( 'Button1' )
        button2 = QPushButton( 'Button2' )
        self.main_vertical_layout.addStretch(1)
        self.main_vertical_layout.addWidget( button1 )
        self.main_vertical_layout.addWidget( button2 )

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    programWindow = ProgramWindow()

    programWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the example!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do! It is just a sad I need this hack to set the layout.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to use QMainWindow is having a "centralWidget", set this central widget with your layout , and you got it.
See [setCentralWiget](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget)