# pyqt: remove layout from qlineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, qlineedit, qlayout

i have a QlineEditText which is given Qlayout by me i want to update it but it says:

> QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QLineEdit "lineEdit_2", which already has a layout

```
MTL.Convert(self.lineEdit_2,'$' + str(self.lineEdit.text()) + '$')

class MathTextLabel(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    #def __init__(self, mathText, parent=None, **kwargs):
    def Convert(txt, mathText):
        super(QtWidgets.QWidget, txt)

        l=QVBoxLayout(txt)

        l.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        r,g,b,a=txt.palette().base().color().getRgbF()

        txt._figure=Figure()

        txt._canvas=FigureCanvas(txt._figure)

        l.addWidget(txt._canvas)

        txt._figure.clear()

        text=txt._figure.suptitle(
            mathText,
            x=0.0,
            y=1.0,
            horizontalalignment='left',
            verticalalignment='top',
            size=QtGui.QFont().pointSize()*2
        )
```

this works 1st time converting my Latex to equation in a layout inplace of my 2nd QlineEditText
but when i press the button again after changing the latex Eq in the 1st Textbox it says:

> QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QLineEdit "lineEdit_2", which already has a layout

Comment: See if this post helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450598/qlayout-attempting-to-add-qlayout-to-qwidget-which-already-has-a-layout

Comment: no that does'nt help

Comment: @shafay provide a [mre]